# SQL how to count distinct id in changing time ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, count, pivot, date-arithmetic

I want to count the distinct number of fd_id over the time between today and yesterday, between today and 3 days ago, between today and 5 days ago, between today and 7 days ago, between today and 15 days ago, between today and 30 days ago.

My data table looks like the following:

```
     user_id.  fd_id.  date
      1.        123a.  20201010
      1.        123a.  20201011
      1.        124a.  20201011
      ...
```

and the desired result is of the following format:

```
    user_id    count_fd_id_1d  count_fd_id_3d ... count_fd_id_30d
```

Specifically, I know I can do the following 6 times and join them together (some column bind method):

```
select user_id, count(distinct fd_id) as count_fd_id_1d
from table 
where date <= today and date >= today-1 (#change this part for different dates)

select user_id, count(distinct fd_id) as count_fd_id_3d
from table 
where date <= today and date >= today-3 (#change this part for different dates)
...
```

I am wondering how I may do this in one shot without running almost identical code for 6 times.

Comment: So, the date column is not storing standard date format? I mean the column datatype is not `DATE` or `DATETIME`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select user_id,
    count(distinct case when date >= current_date - 1 day and date < current_date then fd_id end) as cnt_1d,
    count(distinct case when date >= current_date - 3 day and date < current_date then fd_id end) as cnt_3d,
    ...
from mytable
goup by user_id
```

You can play around with the date expressions to set the ranges you want. The above works on entire days, and does not include the current day.

Answer (score 0):

If the `date` column in the the table really does look like that (not in date/datetime format), I think you need to use `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert it to date format then uses `DATEDIFF` to check the date differences. Consider this example query:

```
SELECT user_id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN ddiff=1 THEN cn END) AS count_fd_id_1d,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ddiff=2 THEN cn END) AS count_fd_id_2d,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ddiff=3 THEN cn END) AS count_fd_id_3d,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ddiff=4 THEN cn END) AS count_fd_id_4d,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ddiff=5 THEN cn END) AS count_fd_id_5d
FROM (SELECT user_id, 
             DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), STR_TO_DATE(DATE,'%Y%m%d')) ddiff, 
             COUNT(DISTINCT fd_id) cn
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY user_id, ddiff) A
GROUP BY user_id;
```

At the moment, if you check date value simply by using direct subtraction, you'll get incorrect result. For example:

```
*your current date value - how many days:
'20201220' - 30 = '20201190' <-- this is not correct.

*if you convert the date value and using the same subtraction:
STR_TO_DATE('20201220','%Y%m%d') - 30 = '20201190' <-- still get incorrect.

*convert date value then uses INTERVAL for the date subtraction:
STR_TO_DATE('20201220','%Y%m%d') - INTERVAL 30 DAY = '2020-11-20'
OR
DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE('20201220','%Y%m%d'),INTERVAL 30 DAY) = '2020-11-20'

*IF your date column is storing standard date format value, then omit STR_TO_DATE
'2020-12-20' - INTERVAL 30 DAY = '2020-11-20'
OR
DATE_SUB('2020-12-20',INTERVAL 30 DAY) = '2020-11-20'
```

Check out more [date manipulation in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

For the question, [I made a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5e039e588c3c63865c20350c38d68f46) with a bunch of testing.